# php returns different mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

I have just moved my host to another machine but now a problem has occured. I get different mysql results from php. To be more spefecific, php returns the last result when i got back-up. I am checking database via mysql console but there are new entries. But php continues to return the old results. What do i need to do fix this?

P.S i can download php files which are on my new host. I can see the source code. Weird...

Thank you.

Comment: Did you correctly change the host in your php files?

Comment: mb check you app config...it could be using old db connection

Comment: you mean host? couldn't follow you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your php might still be connecting to the old database
2. If you can download the php files, your server isn't set up to run PHP and/or has a mis-configured .htaccess file

Comment: db's are ok. i am using 'localhost'. So there should be no problem.

Comment: Is your configuration panel under an IP or the hosts domain? It could be possible the domain hasn't been sent to the new server yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database connection code.

It's possible that you're connecting to a remote host, rather than 'localhost':

```
$mysql_connection = mysql_connect('mysql.example.com', 'user', 'pass');
```

There is another possibility, different databases:

```
mysql_select_db('using_old_db', $mysql_connection);
```

Comment: I think problem lies within misconfigured php files. .htaccess files is okay. no problem with that. How can i configure php files on server?